# How to set a textbox to allow only numbers, one (1) comma, AND a dash (for negative numbers) at the beginning

Tags: c#, textbox, keypress

This is one is a different box than the usual "i want only numbers in a textBox"

I came across with the need to use **negative** numbers, and I'd rather take them in a text box.

So far we can easily set decimals using the following code

```
  private void textBox_KeyPress_1(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) &&
          (e.KeyChar != ','))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        // only allow one decimal point
        if ((e.KeyChar == ',') && ((sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf(',') > -1))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

And hooking it on the desired boxes in the designer
    this.textBoxXX.KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(this.textBox_KeyPress_1);

So far so good, but, what if i need to add a "-" and allow it only in the beginning of the code? any hint?

Comment: `if (TextBox.Text.StartsWith('-')) { ... }`?

Comment: add a vaildation function and validate the whole text, discard the keypress if the new whole text is invalid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try regular expressions like

```
^[0-9]([.,][0-9]{1,3})?$
```

or

```
^-?\d*\.?\d*
```

Here is an example of validation method

```
private void ValidateText(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txtBox = sender as TextBox;
    String strpattern = @"^-?\d*\.?\d*"; //Pattern is Ok
    Regex regex = new Regex(strpattern);
    if (!regex.Match(txtBox.Text).Success)
    {
        // passed
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no idea how to implement those, can you point me to a good thread about it? Everyone seems to know how to do it judging by the comments

Comment: You can have a validation method private void ValidateText(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txtBox = sender as TextBox;
    String strpattern = @"^[0-9]([.,][0-9]{1,3})?$"; //Pattern is Ok
    Regex regex = new Regex(strpattern);
    if (!regex.Match(txtBox.Text).Success)
    {
        // passed
    }
}

Comment: Am I supposed to only use `ValidateText(textBox, e);`  and if he passes he does whatever follows the method? @Corina Gheorghe The thing is, I placed it inside the textBox_Changed method, and it worked, which is amazing by the way. But I don't understand how could he make the rest of textBox_Changed operate or not if I didn't place anything inside the `//passed`

Comment: I used it like this, i did a copy paste of that method exactly as you posted it. http://puu.sh/goPzY/11552a1168.png  When placed inside the textBox_Changed, he would only do the tryParse if the code was valid (negative, and with number), is this how it's supposed to work? If it is, I'm really amazed, honest!

Answer (score 1):

What about changing your textbox to [MaskedTextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx) having `Mask` something like `#99990.999`?

It allows you to enter both positive and negative decimal numbers, length and precision are determined by quantity of `9` in mask.

Here `9` is optional digit, `0` is mandatory digit, `.` is culture-appropriate decimal placeholder and `#` is digit, space or `+` or `-`.

See masking elements [definition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask.aspx) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

on the asp side of the page, you can shrink down the options using the Validator property.. ex

```
<fwc:ValidatorTextBox ID="Text1" runat="server" Validator="NumberDot" Width="158px" MaxLength="23"/>
```

this feature allows numbers, dashes dots, etc.

on the top of the page you can add a keyPress listener through javascript to block out what you don't want, or to trigger a submit on [Enter] keyUp.

```
    document.getElementById("<%=Text1.ClientID%>").addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
            var key = event.keyCode;

            //enter ascii key number for key you are testing for.
            if (key == 99) { //write code for what to do here
             // you should be able to block the key from processing here.
            }
        });
```